# TS-Jest not resolving tsconfig paths

Tags: typescript, jestjs, tsconfig, ts-jest, tsconfig-paths

I have already added these paths to `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["ESNext"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "ES2020",
        "outDir": "lib",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@lambdas/*": ["src/lambdas/*"],
            "@services/*": ["src/services/*"],
            "@types/*": ["src/@types/*"],
            "@configs/*": ["src/configs/*"],
            "@database/*": ["src/database/*"],
            "@entities/*": ["src/entities/*"],
            "@validations/*": ["src/validations/*"],
            "#serverless/*": ["serverless/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "serverless.ts"],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules/**/*",
        ".serverless/**/*",
        ".webpack/**/*",
        "_warmup/**/*",
        ".vscode/**/*"
    ]
}
```

And in the `jest.config.js` I added this:

```js
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest/utils');
// eslint-disable-next-line import/extensions
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig.json');

// module.exports = { ...
moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths),
// ...
```

But I still have the same behaviour: the intellisense doesn't even load the possible custom paths like those listed above as you can see in the image below:
[image: test file]

That happens with this folder structure:

[image: folder struct]

Comment: Add `*.test.ts` to tsconfig.json `include` section.

Comment: @hoangdv but I don't want the tests to be transpiled when I create the production build.

Comment: I have added my full tsconfig.json if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new tsconfig file just for building. ex: copy your current `tsconfig.json` to `tsconfig.build.json`

Remember to update esbuild options in `serverless.ts`

```
...
custom: {
    esbuild: {
        tsconfig: 'tsconfig.build.ts'
    }
}
...
```

then create a new `tsconfig.json` for IDE(vscode) and test:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json", // extend setting from build config
 
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.ts" // include tests directory
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*",
    ".serverless/**/*",
    ".webpack/**/*",
    "_warmup/**/*",
    ".vscode/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Wow, actually that works as expected :D thanks, my friend!

Comment: Nice, but this didn't give the full story for me... But this dude's `jest.config.js` was spot on: https://github.com/codetheworld-io/aws-node-http-api-docker-starter/blob/main/jest.config.js : ) Finally got it working (TS + paths + jest) -- double thanks @hoangdv !

Comment: found the above repo via this [article](https://aws.plainenglish.io/a-serverless-typescript-template-with-docker-development-environment-1f6e6683294), fyiw.

Comment: For me the issue was in the missing `{ prefix: '<rootDir>/` }` bit in the `pathsToModuleNameMapper` function call: after that, ts-jest finally recognized the tsconfig paths! Thank you @user3773048